# Order polynomial of shifted double staircase

Tags: co.combinatorics, posets

This question is related to [my earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/337303/unified-framework-for-posets-with-order-polynomial-product-formulas) looking for posets with product formulas for their order polynomials.

Recall that the order polynomial $\Omega_P(m)$ of a finite poset $P$ is defined by 
$$\Omega_P(m) := \# \textrm{ weakly order preserving maps $P\to \{1,2,\ldots,m\}$}.$$

Now let $\lambda = (n,n-1,n-2,...,1) + (k,k-1,k-2,...,1)$ for $0 \leq k < n$ be a ``shifted double staircase'' shape (see e.g. Figure 6(c) in Stanley's paper "Promotion and Evacuation", which is linked below). And let $P$ be the poset corresponding to $\lambda$ (i.e., the poset on the boxes of $\lambda$ viewed as a shifted shape, with $u \lessdot v$ if the box $v$ is directly right of or directly below the box $u$).

**Question**: Is it true that for this $P$ we have 
$$\Omega_P(m) = \prod_{1 \leq i \leq j \leq n} \frac{(m+i+j-2)}{(i+j-1)}\cdot \prod_{1 \leq i \leq j \leq k} \frac{(m+i+j-1)}{(i+j)}?$$

Testing some small cases it looks like this formula works, and this is not an example I have seen in the literature (but a pointer to a place where it is addressed would also definitely be appreciated!).

For context, let me explain some similar formulas which are known.

If $P$ is the poset associated to the (unshifted) staircase $\lambda = (n,n-1,n-2,...,1)$ (this poset is also the Type A root poset), then
$$\Omega_{P}(m) = \prod_{1\leq i \leq j \leq n} \frac{i+j+2m-2}{i+j}.$$
While if $P$ is the poset associated to the shifted staircase $\lambda = (n,n-1,n-2,...,1)$ (this poset is the Type B/D minuscule poset), then
$$\Omega_P(m) = \prod_{1 \leq i \leq j \leq n} \frac{(m+i+j-2)}{(i+j-1)}.$$
Both of these formulas can be seen for instance in the paper "New Symmetric Plane Partition Identities from Invariant Theory Work of De Concini and Procesi
" by Proctor (linked below). Note that the shifted staircase is just the case $k=0$ of the shifted double staircase and the conjectured formula agrees with the known formula in this case. The formula for the case $k=n-1$ is also known: in this case the poset is the Type B root poset; see for instance the abstract by Hamaker and Williams linked below.

*Hamaker, Zachary; Williams, Nathan*, [**Subwords and plane partitions**](http://fpsac2015.sciencesconf.org/70990/document), Proceedings of the 27th international conference on formal power series and algebraic combinatorics, FPSAC 2015, Daejeon, South Korea, July 6–10, 2015. Nancy: The Association. Discrete Mathematics & Theoretical Computer Science (DMTCS). Discrete Mathematics and Theoretical Computer Science. Proceedings, 241-252 (2015). [ZBL1335.05177](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1335.05177).

*Proctor, Robert A.*, [**New symmetric plane partition identities from invariant theory work of De Concini and Procesi**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0195-6698(13)80128-X), Eur. J. Comb. 11, No. 3, 289-300 (1990). [ZBL0726.05008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0726.05008).

*Stanley, Richard P.*, [**Promotion and evacuation**](http://www.emis.de/journals/EJC/Volume_16/Abstracts/v16i2r9.html), Electron. J. Comb. 16, No. 2, Research Paper R9, 24 p. (2009). [ZBL1169.06002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1169.06002).

Comment: What is the order polynomial of a staircase (and of a reflected staircase)?

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: I included this information. I also updated to include a conjectured formula for the shifted double staircase order polynomial, since based on my data it is very simple.

Comment: This conjecture is now mentioned in https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.01568.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tri Lai and I proved this conjecture, using the techniques from the theory of lozenge tilings. Indeed, this result is *almost* already proved by Ciucu in https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.02021. We just need to allow slightly more general parameters for the "flashlight" region of the triangular lattice which he considers- and the techniques he developed there suffice to do that. What we are able to show specifically is that for the region: [image]
the number of lozenge tilings of $F(x,y,z,t)$ is
$$ \prod_{1\leq i \leq j\leq y+z}\frac{x+i+j-1}{i+j-1}\prod_{1\leq i \leq j \leq z} \frac{x+i+j}{i+j} \prod_{i=1}^{t}\prod_{j=1}^{z}\frac{(x+z+2i+j)}{(x+2i+j-1)}.$$
The case $t=0$ corresponds to the order polynomial for the shifted double staircase (where $y+z=n$, $z=k$, and $x=m-1$ in the notation of the original question).

**EDIT**: The paper with the details is now on the arXiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.05381.

**EDIT 2**: Soichi Okada has proved an algebraic extension of the SDS order polynomial product formula in: https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.14037.

Comment: Very nice! What is the conjectural extension of Theorem 1.1 that you mention in the paper?

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi: This is something I believe S. Okada is working on right now so I don't want to say explicitly without his permission.

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi: See the update. Okada has proved this result.