# Determinantal formula for plane partitions of shifted shape

Tags: co.combinatorics, determinants, young-tableaux

For $\lambda = (\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_{\ell})$ a partition, a *(weak) plane partition of shape $\lambda$* is a filling of the Young diagram of $\lambda$ with nonnegative integers such that entries weakly decrease in rows and columns. Let me use $\mathrm{PP}^{m}(\lambda)$ to denote the set of plane partitions of shape $\lambda$ with entries $\leq m$. MacMahon (see pg. 367 of ["Memoir on the theory of the partitions of numbers. Part VI. Partitions in two-dimesional space, to which is added an adumbration of the theory of the partitions in three-dimensional space"](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/abs/10.1098/rsta.1912.0009)) proved that
$$ \# \mathrm{PP}^{m}(\lambda) = \mathrm{det} \left( \binom{\lambda_i + m}{i-j+m} \right)_{i,j=1,\ldots,\ell}$$

**Remark 1**: Actually, MacMahon proved a $q$-analog; namely, that
$$ \sum_{\pi \in \mathrm{PP}^{m}(\lambda)} q^{\textrm{sum of entries in $\pi$}} =  \mathrm{det} \left( q^{f(i,j)} \binom{\lambda_i + m}{i-j+m}_q \right)_{i,j=1,\ldots,\ell}$$
where $\binom{a}{b}_q$ is the usual $q$-binomial and $f(i,j) := \begin{cases} \binom{j-i}{2} &\textrm{if $j>i$}, \\ \binom{i-j+1}{2} &\textrm{if  $i \leq j$}. \end{cases}$

**Remark 2**: Kreweras (["Sur une classe de problèmes de dénombrement liés au treillis des partitions des entiers"](http://www.numdam.org/item/BURO_1965__6__9_0/)) extended MacMahon's result to skew shapes; namely,
$$ \# \mathrm{PP}^{m}(\lambda/\mu) = \mathrm{det} \left( \binom{\lambda_i-\mu_j + m}{i-j+m} \right)_{i,j=1,\ldots,\ell}$$

**Remark 3**: A modern way to prove this result is as follows: first note that by doing $m-$ to every entry, we can count bounded *reverse* plane partitions of shape $\lambda$ instead of plane partitions; then note that by adding $i$ to all entries in row $i$, we can count semistandard Young tableaux of shape $\lambda$ with a certain *flag* of bounds on each row. These flagged SSYT can then be enumerated via the [Gessel-Viennot method](http://people.brandeis.edu/~gessel/homepage/papers/pp.pdf) of nonintersecting lattice paths.

---

Now let $\lambda$ be a *strict* partition (i.e., one whose parts strictly decrease). The *shifted Young diagram* corresponding to $\lambda$ is obtained from the Young diagram by indenting each row by one box from the row above it. There are often shifted analogs of all the nice combinatorial results concerning unshifted Young diagrams. My question concerns such an analog.

A *shifted plane partition of shape $\lambda$* is a filling of the shifted Young diagram of $\lambda$ with nonnegative integers such that entries weakly decrease in rows and columns. Let me use $\mathrm{SPP}^{m}(\lambda)$ to denote the set of shifted plane partitions of shape $\lambda$ with entries $\leq m$.

**Question**: Is there a formula expressing $\mathrm{SPP}^{m}(\lambda)$ as a determinant of binomial coefficients analogous to the MacMahon/Kreweras formula?

**Remark 4**: Stembridge (["Nonintersecting paths, pfaffians, and plane partitions"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870890900704))) gave a Pfaffian formula for shifted plane partitions. To me, a Pfaffian is just as good as a determinant. The problem is, the entries of the matrix that Stembridge constructs are *not* simply binomial coefficients; rather, they are sums of differences of products of binomial coefficients. I see no obvious way to simplify the matrix Stembridge constructs. **EDIT**: In case anyone might need it, the Pfaffian formula is stated clearly as Theorem 2.2 in https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.05381 (it does not explicitly appear in Stembridge's paper). I do believe now that this is the best general formula for counting bounded shifted plane partitions of arbitrary shape.

My motivation for this question is that it could be useful for answer [my other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/343005/order-polynomial-of-shifted-double-staircase). (**EDIT**: That question has been answered by other means.)

Comment: Having gone through more literature, my guess is that the answer is *no*: Stembridge's Pfaffian formula (where the matrix has entries of the form $\sum \binom{a}{b}\binom{c}{d} - \binom{a'}{b'}-\binom{c'}{d'}$) is the best known general formula for counting shifted plane partitions.

Comment: Previous comment should say "... of the form $\sum \binom{a}{b}\binom{c}{d} - \binom{a'}{b'}\binom{c'}{d'}$"