# Generating functions for Hankel determinants of Catalan numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics, determinants, generating-functions, catalan-numbers

The Hankel determinants of the Catalan numbers are well known and can be written as
$d(k,n)= \det \left( C_{k + i + j} \right)_{i,j = 0}^{n - 1}=\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}\frac{\binom{2n+2j}{j}}{\binom{2j}{j}}$ with $d(k,0)=1.$

Computations suggest that
$$D_k(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}d(k,n)x^n=\frac{A_{k}(x)}{(1-x)^{\binom{k}{2}+1}}$$
where $A_{k}(x)$ is a palindromic and unimodal polynomial of degree $\binom{k-1}{2}.$

Moreover it seems that $A_{k}(x)$ is gamma-nonnegative, i.e. a linear combination of polynomials $x^j(1+x)^{\binom{k-1}{2}-2j}$ with positive coefficients.

Is this known?  Any idea how to prove this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm upgrading my comments to an answer.

As I've mentioned in comments/answers to some of your previous MO questions (e.g. [Number of bounded Dyck paths with negative length as Hankel determinants](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372811/number-of-bounded-dyck-paths-with-negative-length-as-hankel-determinants) and [Some nice polynomials related to Hankel determinants](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/389657/some-nice-polynomials-related-to-hankel-determinants)), this Hankel determinant of Catalan numbers counts fans of nested Dyck paths (see, e.g., Section 3.1.6 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.2562), which are the same as plane partitions of staircase shape with bounded entries, which were first counted by Proctor (see his "Odd symplectic groups" paper https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01404455).

At any rate, this interpretation means that your generating function $D_k(x)$ is the same as the generating function $\sum_{m \geq 0}\Omega_P(m)x^m$ where $\Omega_P(m)$ counts the number of order preserving maps $P\to \{0,1,\ldots,m\}$ for a certain poset $P$ (namely, the staircase partition shape poset; equivalently, the Type A root poset). The general theory of $P$-partitions, as developed by Stanley, thus says that $D_k(x) = \sum_{L} x^{\mathrm{des}(L)}/(1-x)^{\binom{k}{2}-1}$, where the sum is over linear extensions of $P$, when it is naturally labeled (see e.g. Theorem 3.15.8 of EC1). Thus your $A_k(x)$ is the $P$-version of an Eulerian number generating function, and a general result of Brändén (see https://doi.org/10.37236/1866 or https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.6601) says that such poset linear extension descent genearting functions are $\gamma$-nonnegative as long as the poset in question is graded, which it is in this case.

Comment: Great answer! I knew all ingredients but yet didn't make the connection before reading it...

Comment: @Sam Hopkins: Thank you for this information. There is an analogous situation for the Hankel determinants  
$c(k,n)= \det \left( b_{k + i + j} \right)_{i,j = 0}^{n - 1}$ of $b(n)= \binom{n}{\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor}.$

Let $C_k(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}c(2k,n)x^n=\frac{B_{k}(x)}{(1-x)^{k^2+1}}$
be the generating function of $c(2k,n)=\prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{k+i+j}{i+j}.$ Then it seems that $B_k(x)$ is also gamma positive. Is there an analogous interpretation?

Comment: @JohannCigler: Yes, there is an analogous interpretation. This time $P$ will be the Type B root poset (alias "shifted double staircase shape"). The fact that this second Hankel determinant counts such bounded $P$-partitions is closely related to the fact that so-called "Dyck path prefixes" are counted by $\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$ (see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.1709); briefly, we now consider fans of Dyck path prefixes. Incidentally, these kind of bounded $P$-partitions were again first counted by Proctor, in https://doi.org/10.2307/2045516.