# Hankel determinants of the sequence $(\binom{n}{m})_{n\ge0}$ and related sequences

Tags: co.combinatorics, determinants, generating-functions

I posted (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4363151/generating-functions-of-hankel-determinants-related-to-hoggatt-triangles) this question on Mathematics StackExchange but have not received a response. Therefore I try it here again in a somewhat different form.

For $m\ge {n-1}$ the Hankel determinants  $d_k(p,n)=\det{\left( p(k+i+j)\right)}_{i,j=0}^{n-1}$ of a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $m$ are polynomials of degree $n(m-n+1)$ in $k$.
Therefore their generating functions satisfy $$\sum_{k\ge 0}d_{k}(p,n)x^k =(-1)^{\binom{n}{2}} \frac {A_{p,n}(x)}{(1-x)^{n(m-n+1)+1}}$$ for some polynomial $A_{p,n}(x).$

For $p(x)=\binom{x}{m}$ we get $A_{p,n}(x)=x^{m-n+1}C_{n,m-n+1}(x)$ where $C_{d,n}(x)$ denotes the $d-$ Narayana polynomials (as defined by Robert A. Sulanke, Electr. J. Comb. 11, R 54).
Here  all $A_{p,n}(x)$ are palindromic and unimodal with positive coefficients and even gamma-positive.

Let $r$ be a positive integer and let
$${\left\langle\begin{array}{l}n \\k\end{array}\right\rangle}_r=\prod_{1 \le i \le k, 1 \le j \le r} \frac{n - i + j}{(k - i) + (r - j) + 1} = \prod_{1 \le i \le k} \frac{(n - i + 1)^{\overline{r}}}{(k - i + 1)^{\overline{r}}}, $$
where $x^{\overline{r}}$ denotes the rising factorial $ x(x + 1) \dots (x + (r-1)),$
be the elements of the $r-$Hoggatt triangle which generalizes Pascal’s triangle.

For $p(x)= $${\left\langle\begin{array}{l}x \\m\end{array}\right\rangle}_r$ computations suggest that the corresponding $A_{p,n}(x)$ are also gamma-positive.
Any idea how to prove this?

Comment: Can you explain the difference from/relation between this question and your previous question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403321/worpitzky-like-identities ?

Comment: The previous question is related to Hankel determinants of the sequence $\binom{n}{\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor}.$

Comment: I feel like the same ideas may apply though; now you should be looking at plane partitions in an $n \times m \times x$ box, or something like that.