# $\mathfrak{sl}_3$ webs without faces having a multiple of 4 sides

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory

In settling the main conjecture of [Cyclic action on Kreweras walks](https://mathoverflow.net/q/351718), see https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.14031, a rather interesting object popped up.

Recall from

*Kuperberg, Greg*, [**Spiders for
rank 2 Lie algebras**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02101184),
Commun. Math. Phys. 180, No. 1, 109-151
(1996). [ZBL0870.17005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0870.17005).

that an $\mathfrak{sl}_3$-web $W$ is a planar graph, embedded in a
disk, with *boundary vertices* labeled $1,2,\ldots,m$ arranged on
the rim of the disk in counterclockwise order, and any number of
(unlabeled) *internal vertices* such that

- $W$ is *trivalent*: all the boundary vertices have degree one, while all the internal vertices have degree three;
- $W$ is *bipartite*: the vertices (both boundary and internal) are colored white and black, with edges only between oppositely colored vertices.

An $\mathfrak{sl}_3$-web is *non-elliptic* or *irreducible* if all of
its internal faces have at least $6$ sides.  Non-elliptic
$\mathfrak{sl}_3$-webs with all boundary vertices white are in
bijection with rectangular standard Young tableaux having $3$ rows:

*Khovanov, Mikhail; Kuperberg, Greg*, [**Web bases for $\text{sl}(3)$ are not dual canonical**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/pjm.1999.188.129), Pac. J. Math. 188, No. 1, 129-153 (1999). [ZBL0929.17012](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0929.17012).

*Tymoczko, Julianna*, [**A simple bijection between standard $3\times n$ tableaux and irreducible webs for $\mathfrak{sl}_{3}$**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10801-011-0317-1), J. Algebr. Comb. 35, No. 4, 611-632 (2012). [ZBL1242.05277](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1242.05277).

We call a non-elliptic $\mathfrak{sl}_3$-web *Kreweras*, if it has no faces with a multiple of $4$ sides.

One reason why these objects are interesting is the fact that 
$$
\sum_W 2^{\kappa(W)}=\frac{4^n}{(n+1)(2n+1)}\binom{3n}{n},
$$
where the sum is over all Kreweras webs $W$ with $3n$ boundary vertices and $\kappa(W)$ connected components.  This is the number of Kreweras words, see http://oeis.org/A006335.

The sequence of numbers of connected Kreweras webs, with $3,6,9,12,15,18,\dots$ boundary vertices, is $1,2,12,104,1088,12768,\dots$, unknown to the OEIS.  However, Lagrange inversion shows that this equals $2^{n+1}\cdot\frac{(4n+1)!}{(3n+2)!(n+1)!}$.  Note that this is $2^n$ times http://oeis.org/A000260.

The sequence of numbers of connected Kreweras webs up to rotation, with $3,6,9,12,15,18,\dots$ boundary vertices, is $1,1,2,10,76,714,\dots$, also unknown to the OEIS.

> **Question:** Can the condition, that a Kreweras web only has faces whose number of sides is not divisible by $4$, be given a representation theoretic meaning?

Comment: is there a typo in the question: do you mean "... condition that a $\mathfrak{sl}_3$-web only has faces ... not divisible by 4 [and hence is a Kreweras web]" rather than "... condition that a Kreweras web ..." ?

Comment: (In any case, your preprint is interesting.)

Comment: Well, it's a language problem. But I mean precisely what you are saying.

Comment: @NoamZeilberger: we updated to include some explicit discussion of OEIS sequences you might be interested in- see what is now Section 6.2 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.14031.